# Unable to select DropBox of an element which is a link and a dropbox

Tags: selenium

As part of work I have to automate a certain functionality But I am facing an issue in finding an element.

When I select the object and perform the operation. Selenium is performing operation link instead of selecting the dropbox.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
Xapth=""//a[@id='TabBar:AccountTab']//span[contains(@class,'x-btn-wrap x-btn-split')] which I used to find the dropbox.
```

**HTML content for element 'ACCOUNT":**

```html
<div id=":tabs" class="x-toolbar g-paging x-box-item x-toolbar-top-tabs x-box-layout-ct" style="border-width: 0px; height: 30px; right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 208px; width: 703px;">
<div id=":tabs-innerCt" class="x-box-inner x-horizontal-box-overflow-body" role="presentation" style="width: 646px; height: 32px;">
<div id=":tabs-targetEl" class="x-box-target" role="presentation" style="width: 646px;">
<a id="TabBar:DesktopTab" class="x-btn x-btn-default-toolbar-small-menu-active x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-plain-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-plain-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px;">
<span id="TabBar:DesktopTab-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-split x-btn-split-right" unselectable="on" role="presentation">
<span id="TabBar:DesktopTab-btnEl" class="x-btn-button" role="presentation">
<span id="TabBar:DesktopTab-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on" style="line-height: normal;">
Des
<span class="g-underlined">k</span>
top
</span>
<span id="TabBar:DesktopTab-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el " style="" unselectable="on" role="presentation"/>
</span>
</span>
</a>
<a id="TabBar:AccountTab" class="x-btn x-unselectable x-btn-toolbar x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-plain-toolbar-small x-noicon x-btn-noicon x-btn-plain-toolbar-small-noicon" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" hidefocus="on" style="right: auto; top: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 108px;">
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab-btnWrap" class="x-btn-wrap x-btn-split x-btn-split-right" unselectable="on" role="presentation">
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab-btnEl" class="x-btn-button" role="presentation">
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner x-btn-inner-center" unselectable="on" style="line-height: normal;">
A
<span class="g-underlined">c</span>
count
</span>
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon-el " style="" unselectable="on" role="presentation"/>
</span>
</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Element "Account" image:

[image: Element Account]

========================================================================

**HTML content for element to select from dropdown:**

### New Account

```html
<div id="menu-1037-innerCt" class="x-box-inner x-vertical-box-overflow-body" role="presentation" style="height: 169px; width: 366px;">
<div id="menu-1037-targetEl" class="x-box-target" role="presentation" style="width: 366px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:AccountTab_NewAccount" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
<a id="TabBar:AccountTab:AccountTab_NewAccount-itemEl" class="x-menu-item-link x-menu-item-indent-no-separator" unselectable="on" hidefocus="true" role="presentation" href="#">
<span id="TabBar:AccountTab:AccountTab_NewAccount-textEl" class="x-menu-item-text" unselectable="on">New Account</span>
</a>
</div>
<table id="TabBar:AccountTab:AccountTab_AccountNumberSearchItem" class="x-field x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-text x-box-item x-field-default x-vbox-form-item x-menu-item-cmp x-menu-item-indent" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="table-layout: auto; right: auto; left: 32px; top: 24px; width: 329px; margin: 0px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:0:accountItem" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 49px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:1:accountItem" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 73px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:2:accountItem" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 97px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:3:accountItem" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 121px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
<div id="TabBar:AccountTab:4:accountItem" class="x-component x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item x-menu-item-unchecked x-menu-item-active" style="right: auto; left: 0px; top: 145px; margin: 0px; width: 366px;">
</div>
</div>
```

---

Dropdown element "New Account" image:

Updated Element Image:
[Element "New Account"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOPCP.png)

Comment: You want to select the value present in dropdown right?

Comment: Yes.I want to select a value present inside the dropdown. @Anuj

Comment: Read Post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: One more question, Is it a dropdown or can you  hover over the Account button and get the values list?

Comment: Right-click on the downarrow icon on the far right of the dropdown and choose Inspect. What HTML is there? It's hard to tell what is what from the HTML posted. You need to click the downarrow to open it.

Comment: It is not  a drop down and I cannot hover on the account as well @Anuj

Comment: There is a image you have attached, which is showing all the options under account tab , then how are you getting those options?

Answer (score 0):

From the `html` it is clearly seeing that it is not `dropdown` element.

Try to click on element using `java-script executor method`.

**Note:-** Provide wait before click on this below element, For wait use `explicit wait` method.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl']")).click();
```

**Updated:-**

Try this way.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("your_element_id")).click();    //Click on dropdown element first

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);     //Explicit wait method, wait for web-element till 10 seconds so, your driver should able to find the web-element.
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl']"))));

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl']"));  
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);      //After explicit wait method, click on element using java-script executor method.
```

Comment: Thank you... @Jainish . I am able to perform click operation on element.But here my issue is dfferent. The elemet has some options inside on which I need to perform actions. But I am unable to open dropbox to choose an option.When i ran my script it is clicking on Account button insted of dropbox which navigates to different page. Is there any way to oercome this sort of issue.  Thanks

Comment: First click on dropdown element, then wait for seconds and then try my above code. It will surely help. If you want me to perform this action, then you have to provide more `html code` or provide `site url`

Comment: I have updated my answer as well, please try my updated answer.

Comment: This is the xapth ( //span[@id='TabBar:AccountTab-btnInnerEl'] ) I am using to perform click operation on dropdown element.When I tried to perform operation using this xpath,selenium is clicking on Account instead dropdown link available in account button. There is no point in using webdriver wait if you are unable to open that dropdown. I need a way to open that dropdown.I want perfom click on dropdown instaed of account. I have attached the complete HTML code related to that element.

Comment: Your are not getting me suresh, how may i able to help you, if i don't have sufficient `html` code with me? at-least provide your `html` code, along with `dropdown` element as well. Then only i will be able to help you.

Comment: I have added dropdown element image in the question.Please have a look and suggest. Thanks .. @Jainish

Comment: @Suresh i need proper html content, not an image. First you should read this blog about how to ask question on stack overflow. You are wasting your time and mine too.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Jainish, Sorry for late reply. This is my first time posting question here so, didn't knew how to use formatting.Now I have added the HTML content for the elements .Please have a look and let me know if you can help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Then try this :

```
Select drp = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='TabBar:AccountTab']/span")));
drp.selectByVisibleText("Value which you want to select");
```

Comment: I tried that Anuj. How can I select a dropdown value if dropdown is not open.

Comment: I have updated the HTML code in he question itself @Jainish

Comment: It is not a dropdown. It has some options inside on which I need to perform actions. But I am unable to open dropbox to choose an option.When i ran my script it is clicking on Account button insted of dropbox which navigates to different page @ Anuj

Comment: In some cases you can skip dropdown and can directly click on the value inside the dropdown .
If you provide the proper html then i can try to create a direct xpath without using dropdown.

Comment: If it is working only on clicking then you have to provide proper html to find the xpath to skip clicking on Account tab and directly clicking on the button you want to click.

Comment: Hi Anuj,I have provide HTML code in the question.Could you please have a look and advise.Thanks